# R - Multiply certain rows with a constant

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, multiple-columns, lubridate

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
library(lubridate)
timelist = seq(ymd_hm('2015-01-01 00:00'),ymd_hm('2016-12-31 00:00'), by = '60 mins')

testframe = data.frame(Date = timelist)
testframe$ABC = rep(c(1,2,3), times=2, length.out=17521, each=3)
testframe$ERT = rep(c(8,9,10), times=2, length.out=17521, each=3)
testframe$DFG = rep(c(4,5,6), times=2, length.out=17521, each=3)
testframe$HJK = rep(c(6,7,11), times=2, length.out=17521, each=3)
```

I want to multiply the columns 2 to 5 with a constant, based on certain dates.

I did this to select the rows I need:

```
idx = which(testframe$Date >= "2015-01-01" & testframe$Date <= "2015-01-27",)
```

But now I am having problems on how to select the columns I need and combine them with my index. The constant I want to use is:

> 0.9 * 45/50

Comment: `testframe[idx, 2:5] <- testframe[idx, 2:5] * c`?

Comment: Aw, thx, thats really easy. Too stupid that I didnt get this!